# Image gallery not working well

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an  un-ordered list of 12  images  in 3 colons x 4 rows gallery.
When hovered  a tranform scale is applied.

How can i  set the transform origin for (3n+1) images ( images 1-4-7-10 ) to LEFT
and for 3nth (3 -6-9-12)element to RIGHT?

Im tryng to enter the html and the css here, but  got error messages.

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the `y` value desired for your transform origin (so I suppose is `0`), but if you're applying the scale to the images this should work (add prefixes for specific vendors)

```
li:nth-child(3n+1) img {
  transform-origin : 0 0;
}

li:nth-child(3n) img {
  transform-origin : 100% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code and how i think to get it formatted  by css.

I put a draft working example on the site vsio.ru.

I want the first fourth seveth .... (3n+1)image when hovered  been 2 times bigger [tranform:scale(2)]
and transform origin set to  left and  third 6-th 9-th......(3n) a transform origin set to  right.

( IS IT  POSSIBLE  A APPLY A PSEUDO CLASS( HOVER) TO A PSEUDO ELEMENT (NTH-CHILD)? AND HOW? )

`

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

```
   section#gallery{
          Width:670px;
    }
  section#gallery ul li{
display:inline;}
   section#gallery ul li img{
width: 215px;
height:150px;
border: 2px solid #fff;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;}

      }


     section#gallery ul li img:hover {

-webkit-transform:scale(2) ;
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
-ms-transform: scale(2);
     transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 1px  #999999;
    }
```

`